# Remove first part of list in panda array without warning "trying to be set on a copy of a slice"

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the first item in the combined column. How do I do this?

I have:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,None],
                   'y': [1,3,5],
                   'z': [None,5,7]})

df2['combine'] = df2[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist()
df2['combine'] = df2['combine'].apply(lambda el: [x for x in el if pd.notna(x)]).astype(int)

    x       y    z          combine
 0  1      1    NaN       [1.0, 1.0]
 1  1      3    5.0     [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
 2  None   5     7      [None, 5.0, 7.0]
```

I want:

```
    x       y    z          combine
 0  1      1    NaN     [1.0]
 1  1      3    5.0     [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
 2  None   5     7      [None, 5.0, 7.0]
```

I have tried:

```
df2['combine'][0] = df2['combine'][0][1:]
df2['combine'][0] = df2['combine'][0][1:].copy()
```

I do get the right array, but I get this warning.
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"
What do I need to do to remove this value without getting the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `at`

```
df2.at[0,'combine'] = df2.at[0,'combine'][1:]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df2.loc[:1, "combine"] = df2.loc[:1, "combine"].apply(lambda x: x[1:])
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
     x  y    z           combine
0  1.0  1  NaN             [1.0]
1  1.0  3  5.0        [3.0, 5.0]
2  NaN  5  7.0  [None, 5.0, 7.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
df2['combine'] = df2['combine'].str[1:]
```